# sunspot creates over indexing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I am using indexing method to search in sunspot. I am bit confused, adding indexes to all column in table leads over indexing problems while handling create/delet operation for that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sunspot uses solr to index the data in lucene indexes and is used for full-text searching. It has nothing to do with DB indexing. To know more about solr refer this:-
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/‎

Comment: This is a big advantage of Sunspot/SOLR - fast fulltext search, and not having to have your database index all those text fields should speed it up as well.